# How to set a value with calculations with no setter?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing, methods

I'm in need of help! So I have made methods that already run great and have been tested with unit tests! However I realized that it was needed of me to not have a setter for a get. This pretty much gave me errors and now I'm stuck.

[image]

This photo shows a unit test I made to test out if the debit was valid.

[image]
This was my getter and setter.
And since taking out the setter I have gotten errors.
I know that I have to do something with the return value but am unsure what I should do. Two methods are connected to the balance.[image]

I am unsure on how i'd be able to make the calculations without having a setter.
Please help!

Comment: Hi, please take a little time to read [You should not post code as an image because:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5174469)

Comment: in your `Deposit` method, shouldn't it be `balance = amount + balance;`? You are currently adding `balance` to `amount` which will leave `balance` unchanged. This could also be written as `balance += amount`.

Comment: Is this real production code? I hope not

Comment: @Jocke its not..im just a student trying to do my assignment..

Answer (score 1):

```
bankAccount.Balance = accBalance;
```

In this line of your first example you are using that Setter.
You should replace that line or put the setter back.

Comment: I guess he could remove that line as it looks like he is providing the balance via the constructor anyway.

Comment: @ckuri I have also tried removing that line completely however it would give me an error saying balance is not being used therefore the value of balance is 0.

Comment: @GraceDelosReyes Do you set the balance in your constructor? If `Balance` has an auto-getter, i.e. it is defined as `public double Balance { get; }`, write `Balance = accBalance` (or however that parameter is named in your constructor) in your constructor - the constructor doesn't require access to a setter in this case. If your property has a backing-field, i.e. `public double Balance { get { return balance; } }` write `balance = accBalance` to set the field directly in your constructor. If it doesn't work please extend your question with your constructor code.